# Convergence of circles in Hausdorff distance

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Every triple of real numbers $(x,y,r)$, where $r>0$, represents a circle with center $(x,y)$ and radius $r$.

Suppose we have a infinite sequence of such triples $(x_i,y_i,r_i)$, that converges to $(x_L,y_L,r_L)$, with $r_L>0$.

For every $i$, define $d_i$ as the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) between the circle represented by $(x_i,y_i,r_i)$ and the circle represented by the limit $(x_L,y_L,r_L)$.

Is this true that the sequence $d_i$ converges to 0? Intuitively it seems true, but what is the way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "circle" you mean just the circumference, not the disc.

Consider two such circles $C_1(x_1,y_1,r_1)$ and $C_2(x_2,y_2,r_2)$.  The points at angle $\theta$ on the two circles are
$$
p_1(\theta) = \left[\begin{matrix}x_1\\y_1\end{matrix}\right] + r_1\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right]
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
p_2(\theta) = \left[\begin{matrix}x_2\\y_2\end{matrix}\right] + r_2\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right]
$$
and the distance between those points satisfies
$$ \|p_1(\theta)-p_2(\theta)\| \le
\left\|\left[\begin{matrix}x_1-x_2\\y_1-y_2\end{matrix}\right]\right\|
+ |r_1-r_2|
\le |x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|+|r_1-r_2|
$$
The existence of such a point $p_2(\theta)$ on the one circle for every point $p_1(\theta)$ on the other, and vice versa, shows that
$$ d(C_1,C_2) \le |x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|+|r_1-r_2| $$
This implies that the map sending $(x,y,r)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ to the corresponding circle is continuous (even $1$-Lipschitz wrt the $\ell_1$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$), and so convergence of the tuples implies convergence of the circles, as desired.

Comment: OK. Instead of the last sentence, can I also say that: since $x_i$ converges to $x_L$, $|x_i-x_L|$ converges to 0; the same holds for $|y_i-y_L|$ and $|r_i-r_L|$; hence $d(C_1,C_2)$ converges to 0; ?

Comment: Additionally, why do we need the assumption that the circle is just the circumference? Doesn't the same proof holds also for the disc?

Comment: Your proposed alternative ending is fine.  As for circumference/disc: yeah, a small alteration will make this proof work for discs too.  Maybe for discs you'd prefer to use the fact that Hausdorff distance for convex sets is the same as the sup norm on their support functionals... but maybe not.